# Disable msgbox for Command Button that increments offset cell up 1 each time but shows error msgbox if above row 1

Tags: excel, msgbox, vba

I have a command button that moves the activecell.offset up one cell each time the button is pressed.

```
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

However, whenever the cell reaches the first row the next time it is pressed the following error appears:

"Run-Time error '1004':
Application-defined or object defined error."

Should I implement code to look and see if it row is > 1 or if column is > 1 ??

I don't mind if the function does nothing, I just don't want the msgbox to show up. Is there an easier way that I am unaware of?

Comment: How can you go up one row from the first row??! Add an If clause.

Comment: A simple : If ActiveCell.Row > 1 then ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select

Comment: Sorceri, your comment got me to get it to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorceri answered this question.

his code:

```
    If ActiveCell.Row > 1 then ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

Thank you sir!